# How can I insert a value to the value that i just selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
sb.Append("SELECT u.Reputation");
sb.Append(" FROM Users AS u");
sb.Append(" INNER JOIN Comments AS c ON c.UsersID=u.UsersID");
sb.Append(" WHERE c.CommentsID=@CommentsID");
```

I want to select that value ..Reputation from the users table and then insert the number 5 to it.. how do I do that..? I want the users reputation go by value of 5 in the database.

Comment: *That sounds so damn familiar*...anyway, could you please rephrase your question, I can't fully understand it.

Comment: You can't select then insert, you UPDATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Users u 
SET u.Reputation = (u.Reputation + 5) 
INNER JOIN Comments AS c ON c.UsersID=u.UsersID 
WHERE c.CommentsID=@CommentsID
```

Comment: very nice statement zsalzbank